# HTML Mobile File Upload

Tags: php, html, mobile

I have a php script that handles multiple photo uploads as an array but when I select "choose files" on my ipone it takes me to the camera roll to select photos.

How should I go about allowing for multiple file uploads through taking pictures, not just choosing pictures from the camera roll.

Also, the selection all works fine on the desktop.

Code I have on the front end:

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
```

Comment: does the phome browser support multiple ?

Comment: Well, I'm using safari on the iphone 5. It does allow you to select and uplaod multiple photos. It just doesn't show any option to take the photo.

Comment: Similar to desktop, you can't use camera picture as in <input type="file" />. Multiple file uploading will work by choosing pictures from the camera roll.

Comment: Would you recommend that I leave the multiple option and let users select from the camera roll. Or, should I remove the multiple on mobile to give users the option to take one picture right from the site? It seems these are the only 2 options.